# Hover styling and transitions not applying properly to appended elements in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have an SVG which I'm using as a sort of interactive floor plan.  When you hover over the different areas of the floor plan (`<g> elements`), they expand and float above the other areas.  The scaling of the element is triggered by CSS, however for the hovered area to appear above the other areas I use jQuery to append the element to the bottom of the SVG.

This works fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Can you help?

The code actually exceeds the character limit for the question, so I can't add a snippet, [but I'm made a pen here for you to look at.](https://codepen.io/lthomas122/pen/VzreOq)

Here are the important bits of the code:

CSS:

```
g.hoverFX { 
    transition: transform 0.3s linear;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform: scale(1); 
}
g.hoverFX:hover { 
    filter: url(#shadow);
    transform: scale(1.1); 
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('g.hoverFX').hover(function(e){
    jQuery(this).appendTo('svg#Layer_2');
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<g class="hoverFX" id="Conference_1_">
    <rect x="342" y="206.5" class="st19" width="330.3" height="218.9"/>
    <path class="st4" d="M671,207.8V424H343.3V207.8H671 M673.7,205.1h-333v221.6h333V205.1L673.7,205.1z"/>
</g>
<g class="hoverFX" id="Kitchen_1_">
    <rect x="674.3" y="206" class="st48" width="161.7" height="219.3"/>
    <path class="st4" d="M834.7,207.4V424H675.6V207.4H834.7 M837.3,204.7H672.9v222h164.4V204.7L837.3,204.7z"/>
</g>
<g class="hoverFX" id="Catering_Store_1_">
    <rect x="1264.7" y="306.7" class="st20" width="554.7" height="476.3"/>
    <path class="st4" d="M1818.4,307.8v474.2h-552.7V307.8H1818.4 M1820.5,305.7h-556.8V784h556.8V305.7L1820.5,305.7z"/>
</g>
<g class="hoverFX" id="Clearance_Store_1_">
    <rect x="1112.6" y="180.3" class="st21" width="706.8" height="124.4"/>
    <path class="st4" d="M1818.5,181.3v122.4h-704.8V181.3H1818.5 M1820.5,179.3h-708.8v126.4h708.8V179.3L1820.5,179.3z"/>
</g>
<g class="hoverFX" id="Showroom_1_">
    <polygon class="st22" points="296.8,783 296.8,426.7 537.7,426.7 837.4,426.8 837.3,180.4 1110.6,180.4 1110.6,306.7 1262.6,306.7 
        1262.6,783  "/>
    <path class="st4" d="M1109.6,181.4l0.1,124.3l0,2.1h2.1h149.9v474.2H297.8V427.8h239.9l298.7,0l2.1,0l0-2.1l-0.1-244.3H1109.6
         M1111.6,179.3H836.3l0.1,246.4l-298.7,0H295.7V784h967.9V305.7h-152L1111.6,179.3L1111.6,179.3z"/>
</g>
```

I've tried to find some answers online, but the most useful thing I found was [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120672/how-to-ensure-css-hover-is-applied-to-dynamically-added-element), which I think is a step in the right direction, so hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The cause is just as described in the link you posted.  Moving elements around in the DOM will prevent Firefox processing hover events properly.

One solution is to tie your animation to a class instead of a hover event.  Then and remove that class on hover.

```js
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('g.hoverFX').hover(function(e){
    jQuery(this).addClass("hovering").appendTo('svg#Layer_2');
  },function(e){
    jQuery(this).removeClass("hovering");
  });
});
```

```css
.st4{fill:#EEEEEE;}
.st19{fill:#1B998B;}
.st20{fill:#87BCDE;}
.st21{fill:#D7263D;}
.st22{fill:#042E6F;}
.st48{fill:#7f3d82;}
        

g.hoverFX {
  transition: transform 0.3s linear;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: scale(1);
}
g.hoverFX.hovering {
  filter: url(#shadow);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="interactive-wrapper" style="transform: translate(40%,0%);position:absolute;width: 50vw;">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 2061.2 1110.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 2061.2 1110.7;width: 50vw;" xml:space="preserve">

<defs>
    <filter id="shadow">
      <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="0" stdDeviation="5"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
<g class="hoverFX" id="Conference_1_">
 <rect x="342" y="206.5" class="st19" width="330.3" height="218.9"/>
 <path class="st4" d="M671,207.8V424H343.3V207.8H671 M673.7,205.1h-333v221.6h333V205.1L673.7,205.1z"/>
</g>
<g class="hoverFX" id="Kitchen_1_">
 <rect x="674.3" y="206" class="st48" width="161.7" height="219.3"/>
 <path class="st4" d="M834.7,207.4V424H675.6V207.4H834.7 M837.3,204.7H672.9v222h164.4V204.7L837.3,204.7z"/>
</g>
<g class="hoverFX" id="Catering_Store_1_">
 <rect x="1264.7" y="306.7" class="st20" width="554.7" height="476.3"/>
 <path class="st4" d="M1818.4,307.8v474.2h-552.7V307.8H1818.4 M1820.5,305.7h-556.8V784h556.8V305.7L1820.5,305.7z"/>
</g>
<g class="hoverFX" id="Clearance_Store_1_">
 <rect x="1112.6" y="180.3" class="st21" width="706.8" height="124.4"/>
 <path class="st4" d="M1818.5,181.3v122.4h-704.8V181.3H1818.5 M1820.5,179.3h-708.8v126.4h708.8V179.3L1820.5,179.3z"/>
</g>
<g class="hoverFX" id="Showroom_1_">
 <polygon class="st22" points="296.8,783 296.8,426.7 537.7,426.7 837.4,426.8 837.3,180.4 1110.6,180.4 1110.6,306.7 1262.6,306.7 
  1262.6,783  "/>
 <path class="st4" d="M1109.6,181.4l0.1,124.3l0,2.1h2.1h149.9v474.2H297.8V427.8h239.9l298.7,0l2.1,0l0-2.1l-0.1-244.3H1109.6
   M1111.6,179.3H836.3l0.1,246.4l-298.7,0H295.7V784h967.9V305.7h-152L1111.6,179.3L1111.6,179.3z"/>
</g>

</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but you still lose the transition between normal state and hover, if the solution in that link was correct I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: Also your solution messes with the transform-origin in Chrome

Comment: I have not attempted to solve all your issues. Just the one that prevents the hover effect in Firefox.  You will need to fix your `transform-origin` anyway because you are relying on a bug in Chrome to have the rooms scale from the centre. Percentage values for `transform-origin` are not advisable right now because of that. I recommend you switch to absolute pixel values instead of percentages.